# replacement for img tag

Tags: html, css

How can I replace this tag:

```
<img src="images/username_t.png" />
```

to use CSS?

How can I show an image using CSS styles?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Why do you need CSS to display an image?

Comment: Agreed, without context this question doesn't make much sense.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Use a `div` and set the `width`, `height` and `background-image` with CSS? But why do you need to?

Comment: @Brad : The image is related to style and not content of the page. I also use the same css in other pages.

Comment: Take a look at the SO image at the top of this page, it uses the same `background-image` technique! Probably for *exact* the same reason as Naor mentions.

Comment: @Naor, can you provide a better context?  A screenshot maybe?

Comment: @Brad: Come on, it is just an image tag I want to remove because I have to specify the image location on the html and I prefer to use css. The screenshot is complicated and will explain nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Html:**

```
<div id="pic"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#pic {
    background-image: url('images/username_t.png');
    width: 100px; /* image width */
    height: 100px; /* image height */
    display: inline-block; /* so that it behaves like the img element */
}
```

For css, there are a few options dealing with background images, so check these out as well:

> [background-attachment](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-attachment)  
>   [background-image](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-image)  
>  
>   [background-position](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position)  
>   [background-repeat](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-repeat) 
>   background-clip  
>  
>   background-origin  
>  
>   background-size

Comment: Could the width and height be automatically inferred as in `img`?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this example: [**jsFiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/yY2dZ/4/)

[background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-image) is a great way to implement this. You are given abilities now that you never had with an IMG tag. For example, you can [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-repeat), [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position), [clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-clip), and [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) with amazing ease.

```
<div id="image"></div>

/*css*/
#image {
    background-image: url(images/username_t.png);
    width: 200px;
    height: 900px;
}
```

Now lets say you wanted the user to position the IMG. You can do something like this, using these properties and a little [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
var originX, originY;
$('#image').mousedown(function (event) {
    originX = event.pageX;
    originY = event.pageY;
});
$('#image').mousemove(function(event) {
    var top = Math.abs(originX - event.pageX);
    var left = Math.abs(originY - event.pageY);
    $('#image').css('background-position', top + 'px ' + left + 'px');    
});
```

Comment: Without width and height, or div content, this will show precisely nothing. :(

Comment: You are missing essential height and width, otherwise it would be 0 by default and you will not see anything

Comment: and you are missing any form of explanation

Comment: @Veger, he asked how to replace an img tag with css. What explanation is really needed?

Comment: @Joey, why the width, height, some links to documentation, alternatives, your thoughts on using CSS this way, etc... (see the other answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following; however, you really should only use this if it's for a background as it affects accessibility. Images shouldn't be controlled via CSS as the source of the image is not really a "styling-type" property. The source of the image belongs in the markup unless it is a background which obviously is a "styling-type" thing since it styles the page.

### CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #my_div {
        background: url('images/username_t.png');
        height: ?????px;
        width: ????px;
    }
</style>
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

Feel free to take a look at the [`background` CSS property](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp).

Comment: Could the width and height be automatically inferred as in `img`?

Comment: @Royi, No. When changing the background of something via CSS, that element won't get resized unless explicitly resized.

Answer (score 0):

i think no item behaves like the <img> tag. if you really want to do so you can define css classes that have a certain backround image attachment. but then you always need to supply min-width and min-height in order to see the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if you just want to display an image that you don't feel is part of the content, you can use any element with a background image.

For example,

HTML:

```
<div id="thing"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#thing {
    background: url('images/username_t.png');
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Of course, if you feel like the image is part of the content, you should use an image.  If you want something that behaves like an image as far as user interaction (draggable to desktop, etc.), again you probably want an image.